# ajax request asp.net mvc pass id value from ajax request to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

```
  <h2>GetAllProducts</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgeId)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgeId)
        </td>

        <td> <button type="button" data-id="@item.Id" 
    class="productIdButton">AddProductToBasket</button></td>

    </tr>
}
```

```
@section scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function () {
        //returns all the product ids
        //want to return the selected id of the button clicked
      //  var h = ($(this).data("id"));
        var h=  ($(this).attr("data-id"));

        var productId = (h.Id);
        var s = productId;
        //alert(productId);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/BasketAPI/AddProductToBasket/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: productId },
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
        });
    });


</script>
```

}

I am trying to pass the data-id="@item.Id" value found in the view (JQuery) to the controller and use this value to compare to the Id of a class. I am not sure to get the id value from the ajax request.

```
 [Route("api/BasketAPI/AddProductToBasket/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddProductToBasket(int id)
    {

        var returnAllProductIds = _productService.GetProductsById().Where(X=>X.Id==id).Select(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

At the moment the id from the ajax request (the id is the product id assigned to a button. Each button has a product id assigned to it) is not being passed to the controller. I want the id in the parameter of the method in the controller to be set to the id from the ajax request. At the moment this is not being set.

Comment: Why h.id?! as you've already set `@item.Id` in your `data-id` attribute. Use this in your Ajax: `data: { id: $(this).attr("data-id") }` and also `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. You may need to consider id as string in your `AddProductToBasket` action method.

Comment: Did you check in console any error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

> CSHTML Pages

```
<h2>GetAllProducts</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgeId)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgeId)
        </td>

        <td> <button type="button" onclick="AddProductToBasket(@item.Id)" data-id="@item.Id" 
    class="productIdButton">AddProductToBasket</button></td>

    </tr>
}
```

> JavaScript Code

```
@section scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

    function AddProductToBasket(productid)
    {
        try
        {
            $.ajax({
            url: "/api/BasketAPI/AddProductToBasket",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: productid },
            success: function(oData){
                alert(oData);
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                alert(error);
            }
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e.message);           
        }       
    }
</script>
}
```

> Controller Action

```
    [Route("api/BasketAPI/AddProductToBasket/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public int AddProductToBasket(int id)
    {

        var returnProductId = _productService.GetProductsById().Where(X=>X.Id==id).Select(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        return returnProductId;
    }
```